# problem to install ros-groovy-ros-tutorials

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

> ***Hi. I'm beginner. plz help***

> mohsen@mohsen-ThinkPad-R500:~/catkin_ws$ ***sudo apt-get install ros-groovy-ros-tutorials***

my error:

> **Reading package lists... Error!**
>
> E: Encountered a section with no
> Package: header
>
> E: Problem with MergeList
> /var/lib/apt/lists
> /extras.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_precise_main_binary-i386_Packages
>
> E: The package lists or status file
> could not be parsed or opened.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/53808/problem-to-install-ros-groovy-ros-tutorials/) by [Mohsen Hk](https://answers.ros.org/users/4097/mohsen-hk/) on ROS Answers with karma: 139 on 2013-01-31

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

i did it.run these two commands and it should get you fixed up.

**sudo rm /var/lib/apt/lists/* -vf**

The first command will remove the damaged list and when you run the second command it will replace it with a new list.

**sudo apt-get update**

---

Originally posted by [Mohsen Hk](https://answers.ros.org/users/4097/mohsen-hk/) with karma: 139 on 2013-01-31

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1